# What does -L ${SOME_LIB} means in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

Here I am compiling a C code with the following Makefile.

```
MAIN:
    g++ -c -o td.o -I/home/user/dp/pro/include td.c
    g++ -c -o disk.o -I/home/user/dp/pro/include disk.c
    g++ -o disk disk.o tds2.o -L ${DP_LIB} -L ${LIPN_LIB} -lgnb -lgtd -lnbl -lpin
    ./disk.exe RUN.dat
```

What is the purpose of `-L ${DP_LIB}` here? Precisely, I wish to know the function of `${}`.
If it is linking a library, how is it different from `-llib`?

This makefile is by far very crude (I have seen bigger and better ones). I am new to makefiles, but atleast this one works.

Comment: Please note: `g++` has a manual in which you can look things up.

Answer (score 3):

The `-L` options is telling the linker to add a path to the list it uses to search for libraries. The `${DP_LIB}` thing is how variables are used in makefiles. Presumably `DP_LIB` is a path to somewhere.

All this should be very clear if you just read the documentation *and* the actual makefile.

Answer (score 2):

With -L*dir* you specify a **directory** where the linker searches for libs. The lib files themselves are specified with the -l*lib* argument.

Example:

```
-L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```

means that the linker will look for libX11.so in */usr/X11R6/lib*
(...and in other default places.)